# How to change user password format in suse linux?

Tags: linux, suse

My suse linux systems stores user password in MD5 format in /etc/shadow file. I want to change it to sha512.

Is there any command line tool available for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure the previous answer is actually what he's asking, it's not just that he wants to hash A password, it's changing the mechanism by default to a more secure one.

It's pretty ugly, you'll have to parse out the relevant sections from this VMWare posting....

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1032666

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: That's a great point, I'll incorporate that feedback from now on, Dipen.

Comment: @RossBrunson, you still haven't included the relevant bits in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one liner:

python -c 'import crypt; print crypt.crypt("test", "$6$random_salt")'

6 is the type of hash for SHA-512

Taken from : https://serverfault.com/questions/330069/how-to-create-an-sha-512-hashed-password-for-shadow

Comment: I want to change the password format itself in /etc/shadow file.

Comment: For fedora but it should work no ? 
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-centos-fedora-linux-upgrading-password-hashing/